# I've deleted footer links, but the lines are still visible

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I've deleted the footer links on my magento 1.9 but the lines are still visible, where do I have to look to delete them?

Here is a screenshot to make it more easy to understand:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5um1uoub9apk3pj/lines.PNG?dl=0

Comment: provide site url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using community edition so I am moving forward with my example:

you should learn how to change stylesheets, I suggest you to create other css style sheet and not change the stylesheet directly and customize it by adding the css file rather than changing styles.css

something like:

```
<reference name="footer">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/mycustom.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

stylesheets are in skin folder, it depends what theme you are using as an example:

```
skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/css/styles.css
```

use chrome console and you can find the lines easily remove the **border-top** here and the  border will be removed

remove top line:

```
.footer {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
   ==>>   border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;<<==remove this
      padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

remove bottom line:

```
.footer address {
 ==>> border-top: 1px solid #cccccc; <<==remove this
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: amazing, thank you so much for your helpful and detailed comment!

Comment: I got another question, can I ask that to you or do I have to make a new one? :P It's "manage product" related in admin panel.

Comment: No problem.I guess you should ask a new question, please accept the answer if it was helpful.